# Script to check if two c++ files have equivalent stdout

Tags: bash, shell, c++11

I have three C++11 programs, A.cpp (writing to an input file), and B.cpp and C.cpp (both writing to stdout). Is there a way to compile+run A.cpp, then run B.cpp and C.cpp and compare B and C's outputs, and if they're different then break, and if they're the same then start over with running A, B, and C etc (loop upto 1000 times)?

I'm on Windows 10, so optimally I would like a Python or bash script, but bash is a pain in Windows (although I do use [Gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow), which adds some functionality to cmd. I don't have cygwin.).

Edit: Swapped different and same, it has now been fixed. Sorry about that.

Comment: It's possible. What have you tried so far? Also, what do you mean with "run A.cpp"? Should the script compile the cpp-files each iteration and then run the binaries?

Comment: [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io/) is a nice and lean way to get Bash under Windows.

Comment: @gurka My programs write to stdout, so I have no idea where to begin to collect that data (I suppose route it to some file).  "Run A.cpp" would be compile and run, which I currently do with C++11 like this: `g++  -O2 -std=c++11  \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"` (a sublime-settings file). I also don't really know any scripting languages, including basic things like loops.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks for the suggestion! Does it modify cmd, or create its own shell? The site you linked seems to suggest the latter.

Comment: @JoeBob It's a proper, separate shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

pathA=/path/to/A.cpp
pathB=/path/to/B.cpp
pathC=/path/to/C.cpp
execA=/path/to/A.exe
execB=/path/to/B.exe
execC=/path/to/C.exe

for i in {1..1000}; do
    g++ -O2 -std=c++11 "$pathA" -o "$execA" && "$execA" # Compile and run A
    g++ -O2 -std=c++11 "$pathB" -o "$execB" # Compile B
    g++ -O2 -std=c++11 "$pathC" -o "$execC" # Compile C
    if ! diff -q <("$execB") <("$execC"); then    # The output is different
        echo "In run number $i, the output was different"
        break
    fi
done
```

This loops 1000 times, compiles and executes A, then compiles B and C and compares their output. If it is identical, we leave the loop.

The `<(commands)` syntax is [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution): it basically lets you treat the commands in parentheses as if they were a file (named pipe).

Comment: Perfect! If I wanted to use Z.cpp instead of A.cpp, without having to change every occurrence of A in the file, is there a way to just change one line or some other simple solution?

Comment: Where do you want to change from `A.cpp` to `Z.cpp`? In the script?

Comment: Yes, in the script (so it could be reused for different files). Also you say "If it is identical, we leave the loop."; I think it would more optimal to leave the loop if it's different, right?

Comment: `A.cpp` is only referenced once, so if you change it to something else, that something else will be used. The question says "if they're the same then break, if they're different then start over", which is what the script does.

Comment: Ah I misstated my intention; it as supposed to break if it was different, not same. Question has been edited. Could you please update your answer? Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I'm getting an error presumably related to the use of diff when the script is run: `/usr/bin/diff: /proc/11840/fd/62: No such file or directory`

Comment: Let's discuss in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98850/discussion-between-joe-bob-and-benjamin-w